# Does swiper progress event block mousemove event?

Tags: swiper.js

I'm using a basic swiper with no option. Then I have a listener for "mousemove" in the body of my site. I did this to build a mouse follower effect. This works well, but when I start to drag a slide, it seems this event will not arrive anymore and my custom div "used for mouse effect" does not move.

Comment: I have the exact same issue but only when I import the swiper to Angular: the "allowTouchMove" disable my mouse events. Did you finally manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution in the api! You can set `touchStartPreventDefault` to false:

```
this.mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {    
    touchStartPreventDefault: false
})
```

Look for the ***Touches*** section in the [#Parameters](https://swiperjs.com/api/#parameters)

Answer (score 1):

```
touchStartPreventDefault: false
```

causes firefox swipe bug.

You can use `pointermove` instead of `mousemove`.

Answer (score 0):

Bro after full day of testing this is what finally worked

```
const slider = new Swiper(e, {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  direction: 'horizontal',
  speed: 200,
  loop: true,
  touchStartPreventDefault: false,
  allowTouchMove: true,
})
```